# ClientCertifcates is empty in the request when web service is called

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

The certificate is for my development machine on localhost.

When calling ASMX web service my client certificate is empty on the receiving end of the web service. Beforehand the client certificate is found via its thumbprint and successfully added to the request.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, _CertificateThumbprint,true);
```

Therefore i called verify method via X509Chain.ChainElements and it returns false and i can debug and i see a status of RevocationStatusUnknown.

[image: RevocationStatusUnknown debug status]

So then i attempted to build its chain policy via the code below but the certificate is still missing on the receiving end.

```
 X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();

 X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
 X509ChainPolicy chainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy()
 {
     RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
     RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain,
     VerificationFlags =  X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag
 };
 chain.ChainPolicy = chainPolicy;
 chain.Build(certs[0]);
```

On the certification file itself I run the following in command line..

```
certutil  -f -urlfetch -verify SWIMTRAM.cer
```

I get the following information..

```
 Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_EXACT_MATCH_ISSUER (0x1)
 Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
 Element.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN (0x40)

Cannot check leaf certificate revocation status

CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN
```

Note:
I attempted to debug the request via fiddler, the fiddler2 application itself prompted me to save a certificate to C:\Users\\Documents\Fiddler2.
After doing this the service now works via the web browser, but only when fiddler2 is running.

Comment: Do you have a PIN/password associated with the certificate? In that case I think you will have to sign it programatically..

Comment: Yes it does have a password. That does make sense because i was copying over the .cer file was is not password protected when debugging with fiddler.

Comment: I tried loading the certificate directly from the .cer file, same result so the above theory is incorrect. Also tried signing the cert but no changes.